# Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, rest

При запуске моего rest api возникает ошибка:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'spacexLaunchesRepository' defined in
> com.spacexapp.repository.SpacexLaunchesRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean
> property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not
> determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: launches, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(links)]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:53)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:35)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]    at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:161)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
> ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]    at
> com.spacexapp.SpacexappApplication.main(SpacexappApplication.java:9)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
> ~[idea_rt.jar:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not
> determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: launches, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(links)]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]   ... 33 common frames omitted Caused
> by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
> java.util.Map, at table: launches, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(links)]     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
> ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]     at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
> for: java.util.Map, at table: launches, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(links)]     at
> org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:499)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:466)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:227)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:624)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:354)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar:5.4.23.Final]

эта ошибка скорее всего связана с моделью Launch:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "launches")
public class Launch {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "launch_year")
    private final int launch_year;

    @Column(name = "mission_name")
    private final String mission_name;

    @Column(name = "links")
    private final Map<String, String> links;

    public Launch(int launch_year, String mission_name, Map<String, String> links) {
        this.launch_year = launch_year;
        this.mission_name = mission_name;
        this.links = links;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMission_name() {
        return mission_name;
    }

    public int getLaunch_year() {
        return launch_year;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Launch{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", mission_name='" + mission_name + '\'' +
                ", launch_year=" + launch_year +
                ", links=" + links +
                '}';
    }
}
```

мой repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SpacexRocketRepository extends JpaRepository<Rocket, Integer> {

}
```

мой controller:

```
@RestController
public class RocketController {
    private final Rocket rockets;
    private SpacexServiceImpl spacexService;

    @Autowired
    public RocketController(Rocket rockets, SpacexServiceImpl spacexService) {
        this.rockets = rockets;
        this.spacexService = spacexService;
    }

    @GetMapping("rockets")
    public List<String> getRockets(Rocket rocket) {
        spacexService.saveRocket(rocket);
        return rockets.getRockets();
    }
}
```

прошу помочь в исправлении моего кода. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `private final Map<String, String> links;` - так нельзя

Comment: Где модель `Rocket`?

Comment: `эта ошибка скорее всего связана с моделью Launch` с чего вы взяли? Там же вроде как написано `Error creating bean with name 'spacexLaunchesRepository' `, что в свою очередь говорит что ошибка произошла при создании экземпляра репозитория `spacexLaunchesRepository`, а это в свою очередь значит, что у Вас скорее всего проблемы в сущности `Rocket`